# argument is method with implemented interfaces

Tags: java, object, parameters, interface, arguments

I currently have a method that I have to write:

```
public boolean checkIfThere(FoodItem itemToSearchFor){
    // some code
}
```

The problem is that FoodItem is an interface and itemToSearchFor could either refer to an object in my "Candies" class or my "Desserts" class. My Drinks are quite simple. They hold a bunch of primitive type data like String name, int cost, etc. But my Desserts have arrays inside them which may contain candies.

My question is this: when the user passes the itemToSearchFor argument, I wouldn't know if it's a Candies or a Desserts. But is there any way for me to access the array inside itemToSearchFor, if the argument turns out to be a Desserts. Currently, I can only access the 4 methods that the two classes share, as a result of their implementing FoodItem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are several way for doing it.

First way using `instanceof`:

```
if(obj istanceof Obj){
//do something
}
else if(obj instanceof Obj2){
//do something
}
```

Then you can use the `isIstance` method:

```
String a = "Ciao";
if(String.class.isInstance(a)){ //if a is an instance of String - true in this case
// do something
}
```

Again getting the class name from the object:

```
String a = "Ciao";
if(a.getClass().getName().equals("java.lang.String")){ //in this case true
//do something
}
```

Of course `instanceof` is more easy to use. But always better know more ways.

For more you can study about [Java Reflection](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/classes.html)

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution from an OO design perspective would be to add a method to your `FoodItem` interface like

```
List<FoodItem> getContainedFoodItems();
```

Then implementations of `FoodItem` that don't contain any other food items could just return an empty list (e.g. `Collections.empty list()`), while a `FoodItem` like `Dessert` that contains `Candies` would return that from its `getContainedFoodItems()` method.

Your `checkIfThere` method then doesn't need to use `instanceof` checks or reflection (both of which should be avoided if there's a better alternative available, as there is in this case) and just always call `getContainedFoodItems`. You can even avoid checking the size of the returned list and just unconditionally iterate it, since if the list isempty the body of the loop will never be executed anyway.